# When I run cifar10 on tensorflow, it occurs AttributeError: no attribute 'random_crop'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I download cifar10 code with tensorflow from the internet, and when I run `cifar10_train.py`, It occurs an error below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-58-100:~$ python cifar10_train.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 142, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 137, in main
    train()
  File "cifar10_train.py", line 68, in train
    images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()  
  File "/home/ubuntu/cifar10.py", line 121, in distorted_inputs
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cifar10_input.py", line 130, in distorted_inputs
    distorted_image = tf.image.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'random_crop'
```

Is there anyone knows what happened? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is maybe from an older version of tensorflow than the one you installed.

Try changing the line

```
tf.image.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width])
```

to

```
tf.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width])
```